# F# - List Comprehension To Replace For-Loop

Tags: for-loop, f#, list-comprehension

I am trying to replace an existing for-loop with an equivalent list-comprehension but I am struggling to get the expected result.

```
module SOQN =

    open System
    open FSharp.Data
        
    let main() =
        let o = [| 5.00; 2.00; 3.00 |]
        let p =  [| 0.30; 0.50; 0.20 |]
        let n = 3

        let f = [| for x in o do 
                    for y in p do 
                        yield (x * y) - 1.0 |]
                                 
        printfn "%A" <| f
        // Expected Output: [| 0.50; 0.00; -0.40 |]        
        
    [<EntryPoint>]
    main()
    |> ignore
```

Comment: There is no loop there. What you have in `let f = ...` is an array comprehension.

Comment: @Fyodor. Thanks for the prompt reply. I agree the for-loop is not there. The code is my attempt at replacing it with a list-comprehension but I am not getting the expected output -  `[| 0.50; 0.00; -0.40 |]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have two `for`s like that you will multiply out both of the arrays, listing all possible combinations.

You can achieve what you want more easily by using `Seq.map2`:

```ml
Seq.map2 (fun x y -> (x * y) - 1.0) o p |> Seq.toArray
```

I used `Seq.map2` over `Array.map2` because the array version throws an exception if the two arrays have different lengths. The `Seq` version just stops when one of the sequences runs out of elements.

Comment: Thanks for the benefit oy your expertise and the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to "[zip](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-arraymodule.html#zip)" the arrays together, like this:

```
let f =
    [| for (x, y) in Array.zip o p do
        yield (x * y) - 1.0 |]

printfn "%A" <| f
```

Comment: Thanks for the benefit oy your expertise.